# How do I logout from a computer using shell?

Tags: linux, bash

How can I log out of my computer using shell such the log-in window appears again?

I need this functionality in one my Linux script.

Update:
I want to replicate the code working behind the Logout button of my Ubuntu.

Desktop Enviroment being used: GNOME

Comment: I think it will be different for KDE/Gnome/any other window manager

Comment: @Fabio: That would abruptly kill all clients as well. Not really a good idea, as it might lose data...

Comment: Better question for SuperUser, I'd think.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think this does the job:

```
gnome-session-save --logout
```

Also, take a look at the --help output, maybe you want to use the --force-logout option.

```
Usage:
  gnome-session-save [OPTION...]

Help Options:
  -h, --help               Show help options
  --help-all               Show all help options
  --help-gtk               Show GTK+ Options

Application Options:
  --logout                 Log out
  --force-logout           Log out, ignoring any existing inhibitors
  --logout-dialog          Show logout dialog
  --shutdown-dialog        Show shutdown dialog
  --gui                    Use dialog boxes for errors
  --display=DISPLAY        X display to use
```

Comment: This page: http://linux.die.net/man/1/gnome-session-save says, it's --kill, not --logout, but I haven't tried.

Comment: @Boldewyn: On my Gnome, a popup opens when I use --kill, maybe not what is wanted for scripts. I then ran gnome-session-save --help, which lists the --logout option.

Comment: M.: Just checked the man page on my Ubuntu machine, too: --kill and --silent are deprecated, so my comment from above is irrelevant, the linked man page is outdated. (I +1'ed your answer before anyway. Thanks for pointing us to gnome-session-save)

Answer (score 2):

Try restarting the display manager using one of the following, depending one which one you're using. You'll obviously have to have the proper permissions.

```
/etc/init.d/xdm restart
/etc/init.d/kdm restart
/etc/init.d/gdm restart
```

Comment: xdm kdm not available on my Ubuntu 10.0

Comment: That's probably not a good idea, as it will unceremoniously kill all X clients, possibly losing unsaved data in running apps :-(.

Comment: @baltusaj: Ubuntu 10.04 uses `gdm` by default

Comment: @baltusaj: That's because Ubuntu 10 uses `gdm` by default. Anyway, probably not a good solution (see my other comment).

Comment: @sleske: As far as I can tell, that's exactly what the OP wants. @baltusaj: I've added gdm, which is what Ubuntu 10.0 uses.

Comment: @scompt.com: Well, it does not *explicitly* say so. I find it very bad style to suggest solutions which can lead to data loss without at least mentioning that problem.

Comment: @scompt.com Great. That's what i needed.  
@sleske It's fine to me. If the user does this without saving his data before, that's his headache. :P Thanks for letting me know though.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is a bit vague. Are you trying to log out of a graphical session of a desktop environment (such as KDE/Gnome), as if the user clicked on "log off"?

Then you need to find out if/how the desktop environment supports scripting to log out. On KDE for example you can use `kquitapp`.

Comment: Yes exactly. I want to replicate the code working behind the Logout button in my ubuntu (GNOME).

Comment: Do you know what can I use for GNOME?

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit of a hack, but the way that `screen`'s power detach does this is to determine its parent pid and send it a `SIGHUP`. (Clarification: This closes only the shell, so only works if you're running from a console - not a graphical login - so may not be what you're looking for.)

Answer (score 1):

Type in terminal

```
gnome-session-quit
```

or

```
pkill -kill -u {Username}
```